# Meteor MongoDB nested query with AND (two conditions)

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I've been struggling for hours. Here's what I need to achieve: find if document exists where both conditions are satisfied: Field1 = 'Value1' and users.userName = 'Value2'

```js
{
  "_id": "eRotXZoKL4aS3KygF",
  "Field1": "Value1",
  "usercount": 1,
  "owner": "Admin",
  "accessType": "Level1",
  "users": {
    "userName": "Value2",
    "expired": false
  }
}
```

My query

```js
Collection.findOne({},{Field1: channel, users:{userName: nickName}});
```

returns first match it finds. In other words, it finds the document where users:{userName: 'Value2'}, but disregards, or so it seems Field1: 'Value1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter to [findOne](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/findone) is the selector. Try this:

```
Collection.findOne({Field1: channel, 'users.userName': nickName});
```

Mongo uses an implicit AND between all fields in the selector object. Also note that to match a nested object you'll use dot notation to reference [embedded documents](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#embedded-documents) - in this case, `'users.username'`.

Comment: Yes, that worked. Thanks. Did not think I could use single quotes. Learned something today.